# Difference between when Solve returns `{}` and `{{}}`

Tags: equation-solving

I have two `Solve` commands in Mathematica. The first happens to be a matrix equation (not sure this is relevant, but just in case), and it returns `{}`. The second command was me just trying `Solve[x*0==0,x]`, which returns `{{}}`.

Could someone explains to me the difference between when `Solve` returns `{}` and `{{}}`

Comment: `{{}}` means multiple solutions. Linear equations typically have only one solution (or none, or infinitely many).

Comment: To be more precise, `{{}}` means the solution is full-dimensional, see the "Details & Options" section of `Solve`. So `{}` means "no solution", and the `{{}}` in your example means "all x are a solution" (or at least an interval).

Comment: `{}` means no solution. `{{}}` contains 1 solution `{}` representing any infinite set of solutions including countable ones, e.g. `Solve[True,{x},Integers]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematica has good documentation. The first place to look for answers to such questions is in the "Details" or "Details and Options" section of the relevant documentation page: [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html). There, you will find:

> Solve gives solutions in terms of rules of the form:
>
> - {} — no solutions
> - {{x -> sol_x, y -> sol_y, ...}, ...} — several solutions
> - {{}} — solution set is full dimensional

"full dimensional" here means that there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Depending on how precise one wants to be, it might be better to say "uncountably may solutions", since `Solve` typically returns more explicit solutions for countably infinite sets, e.g. `Solve[Sin[x] == 0, x]`